# Editable functionality in uitable is not working: "Table data is not editable at this location."

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I want my uitable to have checkboxes that you can click in it. If I do it this way, i get the warning: Table data is not editable at this location.

As it is now, the boxes appear but you can't click them.

```
 p=figure
 D={'1', '2', '3' ,'4', '5','6'
    '7', '8', '9', '10', '11' ,'12'}
 data=D(:,1)
cnames={'', 'Left', 'Right','P1', 'P2', 'P3'}

table_resultat_nip=uitable('position',[0 200 500 200],...
   'parent',p,...
   'columnname', cnames,...
   'rowname', '',...
   'data',data,...
   'ColumnFormat',{'char','logical','logical','logical','logical','logical'},...
   'columneditable',[false, true, true, true, true, true])   ;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, your code looks alright. Please modify your question and include runable code one can just copy&paste to try it out. Means, include example data and declare all needed variables.

Comment: ok edited it so you can just copy paste it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of the cells you want to edit need to be in the correct format.

There are two issues:

**1)**

```
data = D(:,1);
```

I understand you just want to use the data of the first column, but you need to declare the other columns as well, as locicals.

**2)**

Your data does not fit the `columnformat`, so rather use:

```
D = {'1', false, false ,false, false, false; ...
     '7', false, false, false, false, false};
```

**Solution:**

```
D = {'1', '2', '3' ,'4', '5','6' ;
     '7', '8', '9', '10', '11' ,'12'};


data = [ D(:,1)  num2cell( false( size(D,1) , size(D,2)-1) ) ];
%// where the -1 depends on how many "real" data columns you have.
```

or more generic:

```
N = 1;   %// Number data columns to keep
data = [ D(:,1:N)  num2cell( false( size(D,1) , size(D,2)-N) ) ];
```

All in all, the following code works, now you need to apply it to your case:

```
p = figure;

D = {'1', '2', '3' ,'4', '5','6' ;
     '7', '8', '9', '10', '11' ,'12'};

data = [ D(:,1)  num2cell( false( size(D,1) , size(D,2)-1) ) ];

cnames = {'', 'Left', 'Right','P1', 'P2', 'P3'};

table_resultat_nip=uitable('position',[0 200 500 200],...
   'columnname', cnames,...
   'rowname', '',...
   'data',data,...
   'ColumnFormat',{'char','logical','logical','logical','logical','logical'},...
   'ColumnEditable',[false, true, true, true, true, true]...
   );
```

---

**Regarding the comment:**

Okay, an even more generic case:

```
N = 1;   %// Number data columns to keep
M = 5;   %// Number of checkboxes desired

data = [ D(:,1:N)  num2cell( false( size(D,1) , M) ) ];
```

Comment: I get my data from another table where you can add new rows. Is there a way to set the data for this table so that I just get the first column from the old one and get checkboxes in the new one?

Comment: It works for the first 3 checkboxes, the fourth and the fifth i get the Warning: Table data is not editable at this location. The table that i import my data from is 4 columns, does this have to do anything with this? anyways, thanks for all the help you have given me so far!

Comment: Well I assumed your data has the same number of columns as your table, as in your example. Have a look at the last edit. Please also accept the answer if it finally solved your problem. Thanks!